# NPE when injecting a static @Bean with AndroidAnnotations

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, static, android-annotations

I am trying to inject a static field using the `@Bean` from [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations):

```
@EBean
public class LogUtil {

    @Bean(CrashReporting.class) static Reporting reporting;

    public static void log(Activity activity, String method) {
        reporting.log(activity.getClass().getName() + ":" + method);
    }

}
```

..

```
@EBean(scope = EBean.Scope.Singleton)
public class CrashReporting implements Reporting {

    @Override
    public void log(String text) {
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), text);
    }

}
```

The `reporting` field is null at runtime:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke interface method 
'void com.example.staticinjection.Reporting.log(java.lang.String)' 
on a null object reference
    at com.example.staticinjection.LogUtil.log(LogUtil.java:15)
    at com.example.staticinjection.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    ...
```

## Demo project

- I created [this demo project](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/StaticInjection) for you to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

The injected fields are only available after an [`@AfterInject`](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance-custom-classes#executing-code-after-dependency-injection) annotated method is called. Are you accessing the field after that point?

EDIT: you cannot really use static injection. You have to inject the bean to an instance member of the Activity:

```
@EActivity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bean
    LogUtil logger;

    @AfterInject
    public void afterInject() {
        logger.log(this, "AFTERINJECT");
    }
}

@EBean
public class LogUtil {

    @Bean(CrashReporting.class) Reporting reporting;

    public void log(Activity activity, String method) {
        reporting.log(activity.getClass().getName() + ":" + method);
    }

}
```

Comment: I updated the **demo project** following your suggestion. The `NullPointerException` remains, though. Injection does not happen.

Comment: OK, i see now what is the problem.